# How to Mirror Eye

Tags: transforms, mirror

I am fairly new to Blender, but I can't figure out how to properly mirror my characters eye. I tried joining the eye ball and lid to the body and just applying the mirror modifier, but for some reason that messes with the transparency shader of the cornea. So, I tried setting the origin as the 3D cursor and moving scaling it on the X axis to -1, but for some reason this was the result,

[image: Eye]

for some reason it messes with the rotation of the eyelids, it doesn't fix if I rotate them 180 degrees on the X axis but for some reason it doesn't do anything? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you scale something by a negative value the normals will get flipped too. So make sure to select your Mesh in Edit Mode and hit Shift + N after you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

first, add mirror modifier on the eye and add an empty  .. take empty to the center of both eye (  it's the nose ) and then select or pick the empty in the modifier and choose which axis u want to mirror hope it helps ;)

Comment: It works pretty well, but is there anyway to apply the mirror modifier to children too? It only takes the cornea with it, and might be a pain to do  this with the iris, cornea, and both eyelids lol
Edit: Dumb me, I just realized I could use the same empty object for all of the mirrors :P
Thanks, it worked!